# How to "Evaluate and Log" a formatted string in Goland IDE breakpoint?

Tags: go, debugging, breakpoints, goland

I'm using the ["Evaluate and log" feature](https://twitter.com/i/status/1019254714003836928) in Goland and can only print a string or a variable.

How can I log a string with a variable value embedded? I want something like `"foo is now {fooVariableName}"`, but go doesn't have formatted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This IDE feature says "evaluate", which means you can put some expression there. So you can use something like this (if your variable is a string):

```
"foo is now " + fooVariableName
```

Or, if your variable is numeric

```
"foo is now " + strconv.Itoa(fooVariableName)
```

However it seems to be quite limited as you can only use already imported functions. So in example above you'll only be able to use `strconv.Itoa` if it's already used somewhere in your module.

P.S. I didn't know about this function, but tried and it looks useful, although a bit limited

Comment: I tried concatenating with the "+" symbol and it didn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly. But only if the variable is also a string. If it isn't, then you'll need to convert it to string somehow, like in my example with a number.